# Vuejs pulling database from Sqlite3 over axios; DOM not re-rendering

Tags: sqlite, vue.js, flask, axios

So I am working on a project including Flask, VueJS, Sqlite3 and Axios. On the VueJS side, using a 'GET' request I am getting all the database data and saving it in a JavaScript array. I am trying to iterate through the array and show all the database information in HTML. If I 'refresh' the page the information is displayed. But I would like the information to update 'live' when I add information to the database from a 'POST' axios request to FLASK.

I just put the critical code down below; I tried to make it shorter.

So the axios 'GET' request fetches the entire sqlite3 database; then saves it in the 'database[]' array

The database has three columns; id, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME

```
@app.route('/api/database', methods = ['POST'])
def database_write():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        conn = sql.connect('test.sqlite3')
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO DATABASE (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) \
            VALUES (?, ?)", (request.json[0], request.json[1]))
        conn.commit()
        print("Records created successfully")
        conn.close()
        return("OK")

@app.route('/api/getdatabase', methods = ['GET'])
def database_get():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        conn = sql.connect('test.sqlite3')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATABASE ORDER By id")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        return jsonify(rows)
```

```
<template>
        <div class="form-group col-6">
          <input class="form-control" v-model="form1" type="text">
          <input class="form-control" v-model="form2" type="text">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" @click='writeToDatabase'>Submit</button>
        </div>
          <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="database in database" :key="database[0]">
                <td>{{ database[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ database[2] }}</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="deleteDatabaseValue(database)">Delete</button>
                  </div>
              </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
</template>
<script>
  data () {
    return {
      form1: "",
      form2: "",
      database: [],
    }
  },
    writeToDatabase () {
      const path = `http://localhost:5000/api/database`
      axios.post(path, [this.form1, this.form2])
      this.form1 = ""
      this.form2 = ""

    },
    getDatabase() {
      const path = 'http://localhost:5000/api/getdatabase'
      axios.get(path)
        .then((response) => {
          // console.log(res.data)
          this.database = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
  created() {
    this.getDatabase();
  },
</script>
```

I want the v-for to render anytime I add a value to the database or delete a value from the database. It only rerenders when I refresh the page manually and the 'created()' function is called which resets the database.

Comment: Just re-run `getDatabase()` after writing, eg `axios.post(...).then(() => this.getDatabase())`

Comment: Works, thank you. I forgot to put it in a lamba function when I tried that earlier. Thank you.